# Email Signature Issue on replies

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have recently had some email signatures created and they look great on the outgoing but they can have a few emails on receipt or reply;

1. Logo gets squashed and sometimes the logo goes very big on reply.
2. The font colour turns black when receiving an email or when sending a reply.
3. See the attached photo for how it sometimes looks and the bar goes across the screen

I use Thunderbird in order to send the emails, though I do not know if this has any bearing.

If anyone has any suggestions in order to clean these up, I would be much appreciated.

```
    <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="">
  </head>
  <body style="background:#eee;padding:0;margin:0;">

    <div style="width:600px;background:#fff;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
      <div style="padding:15px 0px;background:#0c6eb7;color:#fff;">
        <div style="padding:5px 15px;">
          <h2 style="margin:0;font-size:18px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:black;">Health Your Way</h2>
          <h3 style="margin:0;margin-bottom:3px;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;">&nbsp;</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="padding:15px 15px;">
          <p style="margin-top:0px;"></p>
          <h4 style="margin:0;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#0c6eb7;">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vyyo3Cs.png" style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <a href="mailto:admin@healthyourway.co.uk" style="color:inherit;text-decoration:none;">admin@healthyourway.co.uk</a>
              <b style="display:inline-block;margin:0px 10px;font-weight:normal;">|</b>
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Uwbw49m.png" style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <a href="tel:08006446414" style="color:inherit;text-decoration:none;">0800 644 6414</a>
              <b style="display:inline-block;margin:0px 10px;font-weight:normal;">|</b>
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/jpcSK1r.png" style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <a href="http://www.healthyourway.co.uk" style="color:inherit;text-decoration:none;">healthyourway.co.uk</a>
          </h4>
          <h4 style="margin:0;margin-top:10px;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#0c6eb7;">
              <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bBNmf7g.png" style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:calc(100% - 30px);">Queens Gardens Business Centre, 31 Ironmarket, Newcastle-under-Lyme<br>Staffordshire, ST5 1RP</div>
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div style="width:100%;background:#fff;border-top:1px solid #eee;">
        <div style="padding:15px;padding-bottom:1px;color:#cccccc;font-size:11px;">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZSms6VI.jpg" style="height:60px;margin-right:10px;">
          <img src="http://i.imgur.com/sXHE0gU.jpg" style="height:60px;">
          <p>This message may contain confidential information. If you are not the intended recipient please inform the sender that you have received the message in error before deleting it.
Please do not disclose, copy or distribute information in this e-mail or take any action in reliance on its contents: to do so is strictly prohibited and may be unlawful.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Massive Logo and Long Blue Bar]

[image: Black Text on Logo]

[image: Stretched Logos]

[image: No images]

Comment: Do you have any kind of code that implements the signature to work with ?

Comment: Also, different E-mail clients can process styling differently. You say you are using Thunderbird to *send* the E-mails, but what client is **receiving** them in that format? Are you looking at the `Sent` folder in Thunderbird?

Comment: Code added above, sorry. Clients are sending it back and therefore can't be sure what email client they are using but the stretched logo is on iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made minor adjustments to the code you pasted in your original post.

What i havd done is:

- Added height on the footer images (no width). Since there is only height the images should resize proportionately.
- Added colors to the code for text rather than inherit.

Give the below code a shot and let me know if it worked.

Cheers

```html
   

     <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="description" content="">
      </head>
      <body style="background:#eee;padding:0;margin:0;">
    
        <div style="width:600px;background:#fff;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
          <div style="padding:15px 0px;background:#0c6eb7;color:#fff;">
            <div style="padding:5px 15px;">
              <h2 style="margin:0;font-size:18px;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:black; color:#ffffff;">Health Your Way</h2>
              <h3 style="margin:0;margin-bottom:3px;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;">&nbsp;</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="padding:15px 15px;">
              <p style="margin-top:0px;"></p>
              <h4 style="margin:0;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#0c6eb7;">
                  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vyyo3Cs.png" style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <a href="mailto:admin@healthyourway.co.uk" style="color:#0c6eb7;text-decoration:none;">admin@healthyourway.co.uk</a>
                  <b style="display:inline-block;margin:0px 10px;font-weight:normal;">|</b>
                  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Uwbw49m.png" style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <a href="tel:08006446414" style="color:#0c6eb7;text-decoration:none;">0800 644 6414</a>
                  <b style="display:inline-block;margin:0px 10px;font-weight:normal;">|</b>
                  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/jpcSK1r.png" style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <a href="http://www.healthyourway.co.uk" style="color:#0c6eb7;text-decoration:none;">healthyourway.co.uk</a>
              </h4>
              <h4 style="margin:0;margin-top:10px;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;color:#0c6eb7;">
                  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bBNmf7g.png" style="height:20px;vertical-align:middle;margin-right:5px;"> <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:calc(100% - 30px);color:#0c6eb7;">Queens Gardens Business Centre, 31 Ironmarket, Newcastle-under-Lyme<br>Staffordshire, ST5 1RP</div>
              </h4>
          </div>
          <div style="width:100%;background:#fff;border-top:1px solid #eee;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:15px;color:#cccccc;font-size:11px;">
             
             <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="160"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZSms6VI.jpg" width="150" height="60" style="width:150px;height:60px;"></td>
      <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sXHE0gU.jpg" width="150" height="60" style="width:150px;height:60px;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

             
              
              </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:15px;color:#cccccc;font-size:11px;"><p>This message may contain confidential information. If you are not the intended recipient please inform the sender that you have received the message in error before deleting it.
    Please do not disclose, copy or distribute information in this e-mail or take any action in reliance on its contents: to do so is strictly prohibited and may be unlawful.</p></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div>
              
          </div>
      </div>
    
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi @Syfer , I have tried your code and thank you. I still seem to get the stretched images like image 3 above but now when I reply from iPhone, the images also disappear from the logo (I think this is from the iPhone reply side as I can see the images disappeared on my reply box. "You fix one thing... lol" Much appreciated though

Comment: Hi @DavidMason, I changed the div containing the images into a table to fix up the images. I think this should fix the image stretching now. Let me know.

Comment: That's great @Syfer, worked really well and the spacing on iPhone email is great. Do you know why the images would not return after being replied from an iPhone like the image above?

Comment: Your div just had padding and your image didn't have a width. With absolute width and height your div's take up the space like it should. It's the same as coding for emails :-)